NodeJS await moveing on before function returns
i am downloading images using this function (downloads 30 images)
async function downloadImages(imagesList) {
    imagesList.forEach(async element => {
        if (!checkForImage(element.filepath)) {
            console.log("Downloading " + element.filepath);
            await downloadImage(element.image.value, element.filepath)
                .then(console.log)
                .catch(console.error);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Image already exists: " + element.filepath);
        }


    });
    console.log('done');
}

when it gets to downloadImage() it doesn't wait until its finished before moving on (this function returns a Promise)
function downloadImage(url, filepath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (url.toString().indexOf("https") === 0) {
            client = https;
        }
        client.get(url, (res) => {
            if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath))
                    .on('error', reject)
                    .once('close', () => resolve(filepath));
            } else if (res.statusCode === 301 || res.statusCode === 302) {
                //Recursively follow redirects, only a 200 status code will resolve.
                downloadImage(res.headers.location, filepath)
                    .then(resolve)
                    .catch(reject);
            }
            else {
                // Consume response data to free up memory
                res.resume();
                reject(new Error(`Request Failed With a Status Code: ${res.statusCode}`));

            }
        });
    });
}

when run the console logs 30 "Downloading" + element.filepath, then logs done
then it logs the 30 completed downlaods by displaying there file paths ./images/Actors/{imageName} 
why is it not waiting for the download of each image before moving on to the next? 
it should be outputting
"Downloading" + element.filepath
./images/Actors/{imageName}
^^^ (this 30 times)

done


TL;DR function downloadImages = (imagesList) => Promise.all(imagesList.map(async (element) => { ... })
